SharePoint server subscription edition opening word or excel files throwing msofba certificate error
When trying to open any excel or word documents , SPSE server on-premise site is throwing msofba cert error. Our Web Application is configured with Site Minder for authentication. Site is being authenticated without any issues and also all other functionalities are working fine except word/excel not being opened. I am attaching the cert prompt we are getting while accessing the word or excel. SiteMinder team has already added the configs associated with Office 365 apps in their server.conf file. 
